# OracleSQL convert Date fields into another timezone

Tags: sql, oracle

in my Oracle DB I have a `DATE` column where store date values.
All date values are in TimeZone `Europe/Berlin`. Now the application changes its TimeZone to `UTC`, this means I need to convert all existing Dates from `Europe/Berlin` into `UTC`.

Is there a way to do this natively in Oracle?

Comment: Probably, but please show exact table definition, sample data, and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FROM_TZ( timestampvalue, timezone )` to convert a timestamp to a timestamp at a specific time zone and then you can use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to convert it to the UTC time zone and cast it back to a date:

```
SELECT CAST(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST( your_column AS TIMESTAMP ),
           'Europe/Berlin'
         )
         AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
         AS DATE
       )
FROM   your_table;
```