# How to handle SQL-Month query with TimeZone

Tags: sql, oracle

in my oracle database I have a column `BEGIN` which is of type `DATE`. I used to store dates with TimeZone `Europe/Berlin`. Now we need to switch to `UTC`.

The problem I have is the following: Usually dates were stored like this

`01.02.2017 00:00:00 (DD.MM.YYYY)` and when I selected the Month `select to_char(begin, 'MM')`I got `02` - fine.

Since we now store dates as UTC, the date above will be stored as `31.01.17 23:00:00` and when I now select the month, I get `01` instead of `02`.

I am really not sure how to solve this problem. Do I need to adjust my entire query, like this:

`select to_char(CONVERT_TO_EUROPE_BERLIN(begin), 'MM')` ??

Comment: Yes, you need to adjust your query like that.

Comment: Wont it ruin the performance?

Comment: @matthias i don't think it to ruin performance provided to use next to `select` keyword, such as in a `cursor call`, but if you use within `where` conditions and the column `begin` has indexes and your explain plans use those indexes, most probably performance impact will be worse.

Comment: Perhaps you should convert your `DATE` column to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, resp. `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. It gives much more flexibility and you will face less problems.

Comment: Well, 01.02.2017 00:00:00 in Berlin was in fact 31.01.17 23:00:00 (i.e. January) in London. What else do you expect? Two days ago you asked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223425/oraclesql-convert-date-fields-into-another-timezone) how to convert times to UTC. For your problem you have to convert it back again to `Europe/Berlin` - so why do you store them as UTC? It seems to be pretty useless to convert local times to UTC, store them as UTC, and when you select them you convert back again to local times.

Comment: @matthias . . . Do you care more about performance or getting the right answer?  In any case, the performance difference should be pretty minor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SYS_EXTRACT_UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions201.htm#SQLRF06119)

In WHERE condition it would be like this:

```
WHERE BEGIN = CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST({given local time} AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Berlin')) AS DATE)
```

The other way around it could be like this:

```
select to_char(CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(BEGIN AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' AS DATE), 'MM')
....
WHERE CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(BEGIN AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin' AS DATE) = `{some Berlin time}`
```